# NGINX Performance

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, page-speed

I have moved my website on a bundle NGINX+PHP-FPM. This all works good, but I have noticed one performance issue.

It's delay when I'm asking file via HTTPS.

For example:

I created blank PHP file () and call it via HTTP and via HTTPS.

In HTTPS case I've seen additional ~60-70 ms of response time.
And another test:

I've measured page speed of this blank file via HTTP - it's 100/100 score.
But via HTTPS the same file score is only 95/100. Page Speed meter complaints on the query time in a second case and it's those additionals 60-70 ms.

I've used Comodo certificate and in the HTTPS test we have rating A+.

How can I fix this issue?
Maybe I need a lower score in HTTPS test and accordingly lower secure encryption settings?
Thank you for answers!

Comment: Normally this shouldn't happen. It's normal that the first TLS handshake is a bit slow, but after that assuming you have keepalive enabled it shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: I assume that your HTTPS test is the SSL Labs test and here you have an A+. Thats good but SSL Labs measured protocol support, key exchange and cipher strength. This does not score your performance. For performance you have to keep an eye on ciphers (some of them are strong but slow), HTTP/2 support, OCSP, Session resumption ... These features are also checked by SSL Labs but may have an impact on your HTTP/TLS performance.

Comment: If you suspect your performance problem comes from nginx, you will need to provide us with its configuraiton, or at least with a minimal configuration reproducing the alleged problem. HTTP over TLS bad performance is usually (read - almost - always) resulting from a bad configuration. If you are unsure, have you tested the TLS layer connectivity (`openssl s_client` to the rescue)? You will need to authenticate where the delay comes from, all the way from the bottom (system) to the top (nginx application).